# Django Haystack ElasticSearch InvalidJsonResponseError: <Response [404]>

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using Django and the Haystack module to create a search engine. I want to use ElasticSearch. I have installed it and launched it with:

```
$ brew install elasticsearch
$ elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.90.2/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

My settings seem correct and work:

```
# Haystack configuration
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

Here is my search indexes:

```
from haystack import indexes
from account.models import Profile

class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Profile
```

and my profile_text.txt:

```
{{ object.first_name }}
{{ object.last_name }}
```

Everything seems correct I guess, I follow the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#search-template) and this [tutorial](http://nanvel.name/weblog/django-haystack-elasticsearch-example-project/).

But now, when I'm triggering:

```
$ python manage.py rebuild_index
```

I get this error:

```
pyelasticsearch.exceptions.InvalidJsonResponseError: <Response [404]>
```

If someone knows why? :)

Thank you.

Comment: yes limelights it is running on port 8000. :)

Comment: It would be that then. I'm guessing that you're not connecting to the ElasticSearch server since you're pointing it to the same port as the Django server is running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the Elastic Search Server on the same port as the Django Server is running on.

Change the port from `8000` to something else, and then it'll work!